# Permutation of the sequence

Tags: permutations, recurrence-relations, symmetry

Let $f(n)$ is [A059894](http://oeis.org/A059894),
$$f(2n+1) = f(n) + 2^{\left\lfloor\log_2{n}\right\rfloor}, f(2n) = f(n) + 2^{\left\lfloor\log_2{n}\right\rfloor+1}, f(1)=1$$
and we have a sequence
$$a(2n+1) = a(n), a(2n) = pa(n) + qa(n - 2^{g(n)}) + a(2n - 2^{g(n)}), a(0)=1$$
where $g(n)$ is [A007814](http://oeis.org/A007814),
$$g(2n+1) = 0, g(2n) = g(n) + 1, g(1) = 0$$
so if we have
$$b(2n+1) = b(n), b(2n) = qb(n) + pb(n - 2^{g(n)}) + b(2n - 2^{g(n)}), b(0)=1$$
then it's true that
$$a(2n) = b(2f(n)), b(2n) = a(2f(n))$$
Here $p,q\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: @user2661923, I sure you are familiar with the floor function. If so, then it is obvious that your interpretation is uncorrect.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  My poor eyesight; I was overlooking the floor function in the exponents.